# How view the navigation path in the master page?

Tags: sapui5

I have a splitapp application with two cols.
On the left I have a tree that i can navigate level by level.
I want indicate to user the current position in the menu tree by a path.. now I use this trick: insert a button to show the current path

[image]

but i don't like this solution. Any suggestions?

P.S. The path could also be very long and I can't see it in the detail page because the content of the detail page could not always sync with the master page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really sounds like a `breadcrumb`. If the path becomes too long you could limit it to show the two latest dives within the object hierachy which would be like `... > Product A > Info D`. The individual links can be used for back navigation. From technical perspective the path can be obtained from the binding context.

And this is how it could look like as shown in the [SAPUI5 Explored](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableBreadcrumb/preview):

[image: SAPUI5 Breadcrumb Feature for Tables]